# how o open link within webview if its come in webview(swift)

Tags: ios, swift, url, webview, ios9

I'm loading html string by WebView in my app. Current issue is that when my WebView load content that contains another link and when user click on that link, new view is not opening in my app - it opens in default browser. How can I open that link in WebView? Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    //EZLoadingActivity.show("أرجو الإنتظار", disableUI: true)
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let logo = UIImage(named: "toolbar_icon3")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView

    myweb.loadHTMLString(webviewurl, baseURL: nil)
}
```

Android allows to do it with:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
```

But on iOS how can we do this?

Comment: They should be default to be opened within webview unless you override `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`. Please provide some example links for your "sometimes" case

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a url request for you `UIWebView`.

```
yourWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "google.ca")!))
```

If you would like to do something while the web view is opening, you could use the `UIWebViewDelegate` statement.

In your class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
```

Then,

```
yourWebView.delegate = self
```

And finally, you can use:

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    //do something while the web view is loading!
}
```

For more information on UIWebViewDelegate, visit [Apple's Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidStartLoad:)